# A continuous while loop with actions toggled on/off by a hotkey, separate from the main body. How do I approach this?

Tags: autohotkey

I need to have

```
while (true) {
   if (toggle) { ;(toggle is simply set on/off with a hotkey)
      ...stuff...
      Sleep, 250
   }
}
```

running independently separate from the main "thread", which in this case is stuck in a RunWait

```
prev_volume := 20
SoundGet, prev_volume
if (prev_volume <= 32) {
    SoundSet, 26
}
RunWait, some game
SoundSet prev_volume
ExitApp
```

Not sure how to approach this

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to use a [`Timer`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) for your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to use the command SetTimer in this instance:

```
SetTimer, ToggleThingy, On ; defaults to 250 ms
toggle := false

prev_volume := 20
SoundGet, prev_volume
if (prev_volume <= 32) {
    SoundSet, 26
}
RunWait, some game
SoundSet prev_volume
ExitApp

{hotkey here}::
toggle := !toggle
Return


ToggleThingy:
if (toggle) { ;(toggle is simply set on/off with a hotkey)
    ...stuff...
    ; Sleep, 250 ; not needed because timer already runs every 250 ms
   }
}
Return ; needed to end the subroutine.
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. I was confused with thread documentation and the Thread command. imo SetTimer is not descriptive of what it does.

Comment: I think that I made that mistake early on not understanding what "labels" were at the time, as they are simply another name for a sub-routine in AHK.